# for loop not recognizing querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript

Not sure if this is what's causing the bug on my project.

So I have a bunch of divs with the same class, and I'm selecting them through

var campaignInfo = document.querySelectorAll(".campaign-info-container");

Now I'm trying to loop through them with `for` loop because I'm trying to add classes to them on `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

The loop works great but I'm still getting an error on the console

```
for(i=0; i<=campaignInfo.length;i++){
    campaignInfo[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){
            mapContainer.classList.add("map-scale");
    });
    campaignInfo[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(e){
            mapContainer.classList.remove("map-scale");
    });
}
```

The error is below

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
```

Any idea what could be causing this error?

Thanks guys

Comment: Have you checked that the specific element exists? 
if(campaignInfo[i]) {
campaignInfo[i].addEventListener(...)
}

Comment: hey thank you, my parameters were off it was `i <= campaignInfo.length` when it should just be `i < campaignInfo.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error. Try this as your for statement:

```
for(var i = 0; i < campaignInfo.length; i++) {
  ...
}
```